# OpenCV 2.3: How to put all holes for each contour into subvector?

Tags: c++, opencv, vector

for each contour I want to put its holes into separate vector< of holes>. By default in OpenCV 2.* we have 2 options - use OpenCV 1.* tree structure and iterate through it as [shown in this tutorial](http://jmpelletier.com/a-simple-opencv-tutorial/), of get our head around the `vector<Vec4i>` which is a bit simplified but same OpenCV 1.0 alike tree structure which relies on `std::vector< std::vector<Point> >` you can get from `findContours`. Tree is grate when you need to know inheritance - "what is placed inside of what". But often you really need just a set of areas and its holes. (for vectorization and similar tasks).

Currently I have such code:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace cv;
int main(  )
{
    Mat black = Mat::zeros(Size(100, 100), CV_8UC1);
    for(int i = 0; i <= 35; ++i)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k <=35; ++k)
        {
            black.row(i).col(k) = 255;
        }
    }

    for(int i = 10; i <= 15; ++i)
    {
        for (int k = 10; k <=15; ++k)
        {
            black.row(i).col(k) = 0;
        }
    }

    for(int i = 25; i <= 30; ++i)
    {
        for (int k = 25; k <=30; ++k)
        {
            black.row(i).col(k) = 0;
        }
    }

    for(int i = 45; i <= 75; ++i)
    {
        for (int k = 45; k <= 75; ++k)
        {
            black.row(i).col(k) = 255;
        }
    }

    for(int i = 55; i <= 65; ++i)
    {
        for (int k = 55; k <=65; ++k)
        {
            black.row(i).col(k) = 0;
        }
    }

    for(int i = 57; i <= 62; ++i)
    {
        for (int k = 57; k <=62; ++k)
        {
            black.row(i).col(k) = 255;
        }
    }

    namedWindow("Display Image", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    imshow("Display Image", black);

    std::vector< std::vector<Point> > contours;
vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
if(sum(black).val[0] > 0.0)
{
    findContours(black, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_CCOMP, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
}
else
{
    std::cout << "It's a black image, so I'm not going to do anything..." << std::endl;
}

for(int i = 0; i < contours.size(); ++i)
{
    std::cout << "counter " << i << ":" << std::endl;
    std::cout <<  hierarchy[i][0]  << " "  << hierarchy[i][1] << " " <<  hierarchy[i][2]  << hierarchy[i][3]  << std::endl;

    for (int k = 0; k < contours[i].size(); ++k)
    {
        std::cout << "\t point " << k << " x: " << contours[i][k].x << "; y: " <<  contours[i][k].y << std::endl;
    }
}

    waitKey(0);
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

I wonder is it possible to change   `std::vector< std::vector<Point> > contours;` to something like `std::vector< std::pair<std::vector<Point>, std::vector<std::vector<Point> > > contours;` where pair consists of contour : vector of its holes. Is it possible and how to implement such thing with openCV 2.3?

## Update:

What I meant was something like this (bad, bad C style...) code snippet I created:

```
struct vector_object
{
    std::vector<Point> border;
    std::vector< std::vector<Point> > holes;
};

std::vector<vector_object> container;

void store_vector_hole(std::vector< std::vector<Point> > &holes, std::vector< std::vector<Point> > & contours, std::vector<Vec4i> & hierarchy, const int & cid);
void store_vectror_countors(std::vector< std::vector<Point> > & contours, std::vector<Vec4i> & hierarchy, const int & cid);


void store_vector_hole(std::vector< std::vector<Point> > &holes, std::vector< std::vector<Point> > & contours, std::vector<Vec4i> & hierarchy, const int & cid)
{
    holes.push_back(contours[cid]);
    if (hierarchy[cid][2] >= 0) // holes in holes == real poligons
    {
        store_vectror_countors( contours, hierarchy, hierarchy[cid][2]);
    }
    if (hierarchy[cid][0] >= 0) // holes on same level of depth == another holes of this poligon
    {
        store_vector_hole(holes, contours, hierarchy, hierarchy[cid][0]);
    }
    return;

}
void store_vectror_countors(std::vector< std::vector<Point> > & contours, std::vector<Vec4i> & hierarchy, const int & cid)
{
    if (hierarchy[cid][0]>= 0)
        store_vectror_countors(contours, hierarchy, hierarchy[cid][0]);

    vector_object current;
    current.border = contours[cid];

    if ((hierarchy[cid][0]<= 0) && (hierarchy[cid][2] <= 0))
    {
            container.push_back(current);
            return;
    }

    if(hierarchy[cid][2] >= 0) // h
    {
        store_vector_hole(current.holes, contours, hierarchy, hierarchy[cid][2]);
    }

    container.push_back(current);
    return;

}
```

that you activate via:

```
//...
findContours(black, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
store_vectror_countors(contours, hierarchy, 0);
```

Any Ideas on making it more robust and C++ish?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to extract them as a contour tree? Use the CV_RETR_TREE flag on findContours, and it should give you exactly what you want.

Comment: You mean having `std::map< std::vector<Point>, std::vector<  std::vector<Point> > >   contours;` call `findContours(black, contours, CV_RETR_TREE , CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);`? This will not compile (`error C2665: 'cv::findContours' : none of the 2 overloads could convert all the argument types` )

Comment: While this `std::vector<  std::pair<std::vector<Point>, std::vector<  std::vector<Point> > > >  contours;` + `findContours(black, contours, CV_RETR_TREE , CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);` WILL COMPILE AND DIE AT RUNTIME WITH `OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (type == type0 || (CV_MAT_CN(type) == CV_MAT_CN(t
ype0) && ((1 << type0) & fixedDepthMask) != 0)) in unknown function, file D:\Pro
jects\OpenCV-2.3.0\modules\core\src\matrix.cpp, line 1239`